# Backslashes or pipelines in url cordova

Tags: cordova, url

I am having trouble opening a url in an `InAppBrowser` on `Cordova`.
I have the following code:

```
if (device.platform.toUpperCase() === 'IOS'){
            let url = "http://192.168.1.115:5000/Home/GetQRCode?value=" + value;
            url = url.replace(/\\/g, '|');
            alert(url);
            ref = window.open(url, '_system', inAppBrowserOptions);
        }
```

I thought the url couldn't have backslashes on `iOS` urls so I replaced them with pipelines. That didn't work either.
After I read the QRCode the app stays still meaning it doesn't open the page and it remains on my index page where I have the splashscreen.
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes and backslashes are not supported/valid in URLs, besides you should encode your URLs (or your Query Strings) using

```
 encodeURIComponent()
```